# Laravel show different date from my database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, laravel-5.3

I have a problem in my project. When I store value in my database it works perfectly fine. But when I want to show the value it gives me an undefined date that is not stored in my database.
[image: Please See the Image]

Here In my database the created_at field value is 2017-02-18 16:23:37. But When I want to show this in my view page it gives me this

[image: It shows me this]
It gives me the value of 2017-02-02 09:19:40. I don't understand whats wrong. 
I am only showing the created_at field. Please help me

My controller is

```
public function showApplication() {
        $dataList = ApplicationModelOL::leftJoin('certificate', 'application.application_certificate_id', 'certificate.certificate_track_id')
                ->where('application_users_id', Auth::User()->users_track_id)
                ->get();
        return view('frontend.pages.application', compact('dataList'));
    }
```

My view is

```
@foreach($dataList as $data)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $data->certificate_name_en }}</td>
    @if($data->application_delivery_mode == 195126)
    <td>Self</td>
    @else 
    <td>Via Post</td>
    @endif
    <td class="hidden-phone">{{ $data->created_at }}</td>
    <td class="hidden-phone">
        <span class="label label label-warning">Pending</span>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden-phone">
        <span class="label label-primary"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span>&nbsp;
        <span class="label label-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Show all the relevant code please.

Comment: even we `don't understand whats wrong` until you share all related code

Comment: I think you are getting wrong `users_track_id` , as `Auth::User()` always get data from logged in user not who sent application to you. print your query by replacing `get()` method to `toSql()` method and `echo $dataList`

Comment: No @Rishi I checked already. The users_track_id is correct. It gives me all the value except the time correctly

Comment: Yes I am sure I am using the same database. @Jackowski

Comment: get your query by `toSql()` and try to run in phpmyadmin directly

Comment: I checked this. I dont underestand why my database value is not showing on my blade. Others information prints correcly. Only  the created_at and updated_at field not showing

Comment: You're doing a join, are you sure that there isn't a `created_at`-column with that value in the other table?

Comment: Please show us 'created_at' column in 'certificate' table

Comment: I take the silence as the OP has either solved it or lost interest?

Comment: I add Asia/Dhaka in my timezone @Jackowski

Comment: Solved it. Thanks @MagnusEriksson. You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when your MySQL timezone is different from php timezone which is set in your framework.
to sync your timezone you can use following codes:

PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
```

MySQL:

```
$timeZone = (new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran')))->format('P');
$pdo->exec("SET time_zone='$timeZone';");
```

Comment: Could that really explain a diff of 16 _days_?

Comment: I am changing my timezone to Asia/Dhaka. This problem still exists if I changed my timezone to UTC. @mmta41

Comment: I don't think this explains the seconds difference.

Comment: try insert new rows to database and check the field again!


ps: Once I encountered same problem when migrating to new server I export mysql database into sql file and when import it all DateTime fields jump two days back.

Answer (score 0):

With Mysql attributes, you can get different values whether id or created_at(Laravel) if you use join on tables. Say you join three tables the output will return the last column of the three "created_at". Therefore you could just check to make sure your joins are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your timezone in Laravel in your config/app.php.

The param below can be changed to whatever your preference is in line with the [supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)...

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Dublin',
```